# How to implement service layer in python application with abstract class

Tags: python-3.x, flask, web, service, architecture

I am new in python, I am trying to build a three layer architecture in python using Flask,
I want to know how to design service class as abstract class and implement one service implementation class and how should i call service class from main controller class.

mycode is below -

```
from flask import Flask, request

from employee.model.Employee import Employee
from employee.service.EmployeeServiceMeta import 
EmployeeServiceMeta

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/employee", methods=["POST"])
def new_employee():
    data = request.get_data()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)


from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

from employee.model.Employee import Employee

class EmployeeServiceMeta(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def new_employee(self, data):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def all_employee(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_employee_by_email(self, email: str):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def delete_employee_by_email(self, email: str):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def update_employee_by_email(self, email: str):
        pass



from employee.model.Employee import Employee
from employee.service.EmployeeServiceMeta import 
EmployeeServiceMeta


class EmployeeServiceImplementation(EmployeeServiceMeta):

    def new_employee(self, data):
        print(data)

    def all_employee(self):
        pass

    def get_employee_by_email(self, email: str):
        pass

    def delete_employee_by_email(self, email: str):
        pass

    def update_employee_by_email(self, email: str):
        pass
```